# How to enable asp:LinkButton on client side

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, linkbutton

I have asp:LinkButton, input Button defined as:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewPdf" runat="server" CssClass="icoMiniTest" ClientIDMode="Static" >View Office Pdf</asp:LinkButton>   
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="TestEnable" onclick="TestEnable(document.getElementById('lnkViewPdf'));"  />
```

the LinkButton is initially disabled in code-behind as:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.lnkViewPdf.Enabled = false;
    }
```

and needs to be enabled when Button2 is clicked, so I am calling javascript function to enable the link as:

```
function TestEnable(lnkbutton) {
        alert('TestEnable() called');
        alert(lnkbutton.id);
        lnkbutton.disabled = "";
        //$("#lnkbutton").removeAttr('disabled');  //even this doesn't work
    }
```

But I am not able to enable the linkbutton.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

## __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__

Anyone interested in solution to above problem:
In code-behind:

```
this.lnkViewPdf.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
this.lnkViewPdf.Attributes["onclick "] = "return false";
```

.js:

```
function TestEnable(lnkbutton) {
         $(lnkbutton).removeAttr('disabled');
        lnkbutton.onclick = "";    
}
```

NOTE: When setting lnkViewPdf.Enabled = false; LinkButton was being rendered as

```
<a id="lnkViewPdf" class="aspNetDisabled icoMiniTest">View Office Pdf</a>
```

see the style class **aspNetDisabled**, something added by ASP.Net
However setting disabled/onclick attributes from the codebehind as shown above, render Linkbutton as:

```
<a id="lnkViewPdf" class="icoMiniTest" disabled="disabled" onclick ="return false" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;lnkViewPdf&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">View Office Pdf</a>
```

HTH.

Comment: changed the my solution to accommodate .NET behavior when disabling LinkButton controls server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try now...

```
function TestEnable(lnkbutton) {
    lnkbutton.disabled = "";
    lnkbutton.onclick = "";
}
```

Comment: doesn't work even after setting lnkbutton.disabled = "false"; //No postback

Comment: @iniki; did you try this now ?

Comment: Check this http://forums.asp.net/t/1148848.aspx/1?Enable+Disable+LinkButton+from+JavaScript

Comment: Thank you :) above link did help.

Answer (score 1):

In the code behind, rather than disable by setting Enabled = false, set:

```
    lnkViewPdf.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled"
```

So your javascript function:

```
    function TestEnable(lnkbutton) {
    alert('TestEnable() called');
    alert(lnkbutton.id);
    lnkbutton.disabled = "";
}
```

Your markup:

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewPdf" runat="server" CssClass="icoMiniTest" ClientIDMode="Static" >View Office Pdf</asp:LinkButton>   
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="TestEnable" onclick="TestEnable(document.getElementById('<%= lnkViewPdf.ClientID %>')); return false;"  />
```

And your code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            lnkViewPdf.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
    }
```

Comment: tried this, but setting  lnkViewPdf.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled"; in code behind doesn't actually disable the LinkButton... clicking it results into postback.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#<%=lnkViewPdf.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the .Net constructed name in order to accomplish it. The easiest way is to have it set in the head of the page if you can:

```
<script language="javascript">

var lnkbuttonToEnableId = "<%= this.lnkViewPdf.ClientId %>";

function TestEnable() {
        alert('TestEnable() called');
        lnkbuttonToEnableId.disabled = false;
}

</script>
```

At any rate, the only way to get it to work is to pass the ClientId of lnkViewPdf to the function somehow.

Comment: not working :-(  even tried using var lnkbuttonToEnableId = "<%= this.lnkViewPdf.ClientId %>"; but getting error:
LinkButton does not contain a definition for 'ClientId.

Comment: @iniki: Since you specified `ClientIDMode="Static"` you should be able to skip that step and go straight to `$("#lnkViewPdf").removeAttr('disabled');`. That property instructs the page rendering process to give the control the same ClientID as what you specify in ID.

Answer (score 0):

try both of those:

```
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="TestEnable"
    onclick="TestEnable(document.getElementById('<%= lnkViewPdf.ClientID %>'));"  />
```

or

```
$("#<%= lnkViewPdf.ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled');
```

**UPDATE:** Since you are disabling the `LinkButton` on server side .NET strips the `href` attribute from the `<a>` html element. What you should do to prevent the lost of that information is to disable the `LinkButton` on the client and then enable it when you need to. Also instead of disabling it all you need to do is remove the `href` attribute.

So first you need to retain the `href` and remove it so the `<a>` link become disabled:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $lnkViewPdf = $("#lnkViewPdf");

    $lnkViewPdf.data("href", $lnkViewPdf.attr("href"));
    $lnkViewPdf.removeAttr("href");
});
```

and the function that enables it:

```
function TestEnable(lnkViewPdfId) {
    var $lnkViewPdf = $("#" + lnkViewPdfId);

    $lnkViewPdf.attr("href", $lnkViewPdf.data("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the LinkButton using:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    this.lnkViewPdf.Enabled = false;
}
```

Then the href attibute won't be displayed in the HTML. If you manually add the disabled attribute instead:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    lnkViewPdf.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Then you're code will work just fine.

Oh!.. and one last thing: **You need to set the PostBackUrl property for the LinkButton**. You missed it in your example.